# Analytical or approximate formula for temperature distribution in a greenhouse

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, thermal-radiation

Here is my problem: Imagine an hemicylindrical greenhouse, with length $L >> R$, its radius. So we consider it as a 2D problem.
According to the schematic we have the flux of the sun at the $\Gamma_1$ boundary which is about $ \Phi = \Phi_0 \sin \varphi$ and the external temperature is $T_e$.

How do you compute the temperature distribution in polar coordinate inside the greenhouse $T(\rho,\varphi)$?

This is what I did but I am really stuck (I tried a lot of different boundary conditions in fact, found solution that did not converge and so on...):

$$ \Delta_{\rho,\varphi} T =  0$$ Stationary heat equation

and the boundary conditions for $\Gamma_1$ (heat on circular roof = sun's heat + radiation gained from ground - radiation loss to ground - conduction loss with exterior):

$$ \lambda \partial_{\rho} T (R,\varphi) \simeq \Phi_0 \sin \varphi - \frac{\sigma}{2} T(R,\varphi)^4 + \sigma T(\rho,m \pi)^4 \left( 1 - \alpha \right) - \frac{\lambda_g}{h_g} \left( T(R,\varphi) - T_e \right) $$

with $\lambda$, $\lambda_g$ thermal conductivity of air and glass. $h_g$ thickness of glass roof, $\alpha$ reflection coefficient from glass to infrared ground radiation (so $\alpha \sim 1$), $m = {0,1}$ and $\sigma$ the Stefan constant. Then the boundary condition on ground ($\Gamma_2$) is (normal derivative):

$$ \lambda \cos \varphi \partial_{\varphi} T (\rho,m \pi) \simeq \frac{\sigma}{2} T(R,\varphi)^4 - \sigma T(\rho,m \pi)^4  $$

where we consider just the radiation from the circular roof to the ground and the radiation loss from ground to roof.

Then we have the intuitive symmetric solution of the Laplace equation:

$$ T = A + \sum_{n=1} a_n \sin (n \varphi) \rho^n $$

But at this point, even when neglecting the conductive part (the derivatives in the B.C) and linearized the fourth power of temperature according to $T(\rho,\varphi) = \tau(\rho,\varphi) + T_e$, with $\tau << T_e$ it is still not easy to find the coefficients.
Does someone have an idea of how to proceed ? Maybe I should consider only the plan limited to x > 0 and using more general solution... I tried a lot of stuff. Thank you for reading and the interest for the topic.

**EDIT:**

I found something... a big mistake, the general solution includes the cosines part... i.e the symmetrical with respect to y-axis $\cos(2 n \varphi)$ and we can find different type of solutions (constant + sinus + even argument-cosines )... But we should fix in some way the temperature of the soil, otherwise the temperature values are completely wrong.

For the boundary conditions, the "most physical" and simple model I found (the radiation part is completely wrong by the way... we need to integrate the temperature on all the sides to get the view factor... if anyone catch the point this seems almost impossible) is:

$$ \lambda \partial_{\rho} T(R,\varphi) = \phi_0 \sin \varphi - \frac{\lambda_g}{h_g}( T(R,\varphi) - T_e ) $$

$$ T(\rho,m \pi) = T_s + \alpha h_s/\lambda_s \phi_0 $$

So we basically consider conduction loss only and the solution is simple (this is a constant + sinus sum). With $\alpha$ optical absorption of the soil, $\lambda_s$ soil conductivity, $T_s$ temperature of ground soil at depth $h_s$.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty complex problem if you include radiation. You should also include air mixing due to convection. I don't think this can be solved without simulation. One way to simplify things is to assume perfect mixing, so the air temperature is basically constant.

Comment: Interesting thank you. So you mean, if the air is at constant density (no natural convection assumed) then the temperature is constant in all the greenhouse?

I have to take into account radiation because otherwise it is not really a greenhouse, no greenhouse effect (i.e $\alpha = 1$ in the equation, reflection of infrared ground radiation) right ?

Comment: Well, in reality, the temperature will not be constant and the air will be circulating, but I don't think it is something that could be easily calculated. With the assumption of constant air temperature (and constant heat transfer coefficient at the inner surface), you may be able to calculate approximate temperature distribution of the semicircular boundary.
Regarding radiation, you can take it into account only in very simplified way, because every wall surface area and air volume will radiate and receive radiation at the same time.

Comment: The radiation heats up the opaque shelves and floors, which radiate back infrared heat which can not pass throu glass due to its long vawelength. So on way is to imagine the air inside still but stratified to layers of gradually increasing temps from the floor to the ceiling. There are refrences that for calculating the sun enrgy filtered and the absorption of differen materials. You can start by searching for, Solar heat gain coefficient (SHGC)., and materials and finishes radiant heat absorption. Interestingly the glass transmits heat out, and lets the sun rays in.

Comment: Yes I know this is what I wrote through the boundary conditions... but thks for the shgc coeff I did not know that term